# How to deploy Magento on multiple EC2 instances with load balancer

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I want to start my own mageno store on amazon cloud, but Im having trouble understanding how to deploy magento on several differnt EC2 instances to use with load balancer.

From my understanding, I need my application(in this case magento) to be copied to all instances and the load balancer will route users to the appropriate instance. so how do I do it?

Do I need to setup my store on one instance then duplicate it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to keep copy your application on all the instances and the load balancer will be responsible for routing users.

Possible way is to setup a store on one instance and create image of that. And then use that image to create new instances which will be same as the original one. Add all those instances to load balancer.

You can also setup a git repo of your source code (Magento store) and clone them on each server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your answer. I just wanted to know, what happenes when I make changes to stock\item in the admin panel? does this automatically update the store(on all different instances)? thanks again

Comment: Any changes which are happening into rds/db side, it will reflect on all instances. But in case any files/images are getting saved on server, then it will not reflect.